# Reset action cache from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

Is there any way of reseting an action cache using a rake task?

I've an action inside my controller that shows the top 100 songs.
I only need to generate the view once every 24h hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

**Controller**

```
helper_method :custom_cache_path

before_filter only: [:method] do
  if params[:reset_cache]
    expire_fragment(custom_cache_path)
  end
end

def custom_cache_path
  "#{params[:id].to_i}-#{params[:controller]}-#{params[:action]}"
end
```

**Rest request**

```
RestClient.get "http://example.com/controller/method?reset_cache=1"
```